# Why does HERE oauth2 token request api return 401300 with Rails but works fine with Postman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64, here-api, sha256, hmac

When calling the HERE authentication service (https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token) from one of the controllers of the RoR APP (Rails 5.0.6/ruby 2.6.1) I get a 401: "***401300 Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong***"

The Key, secret, Authorization header, content type, request body etc ... are the same as the ones used by Postman.

Postman always returns a 200 OK but the rails app systematically returns "401"

Any suggestions on what the problem is?

```
 def fetch_new_token
    # URL
    api_url = 'https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token'
    # VERSION        
    api_version='1.0'
    # GRANT TYPE
    api_grant_type_for_req_body='grant_type=client_credentials'
    #KEY
    api_access_key_id = CGI.escape(ENV['my_access_key_id'])
    #SECRET
    api_access_key_secret = CGI.escape(ENV['my_access_key_secret'])
    #NONCE
    draft_api_nonce= [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z')].map(&:to_a).flatten
    api_nonce=(0...20).map { draft_api_nonce[rand(draft_api_nonce.length)] }.join
    #TMESTAMP
    api_timestamp = (Time.now).strftime('%s') 
    #NORMALIZED URL
    api_url_normalized = CGI.escape(api_url)
    #SIGNING METHOD
    api_signature_method= CGI.escape('HMAC-SHA256')
    #OAUTH PARAMETERS BASE STRING
    api_parameters_string=('consumer_key='+api_access_key_id+'&nonce='+api_nonce+'&signature_method='+api_signature_method+'&timestamp='+api_timestamp+'&'+'version=1.0')
    #ENCODED BASE STRING
    api_normalized_string = 'POST&'+api_url_normalized+'&'+api_grant_type_for_req_body+CGI.escape('&'+api_parameters_string)
    #SIGNNG KEY
    api_signing_key = api_access_key_secret+'&'        
    #SIGNATURE
    digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256')
    api_signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, api_normalized_string, api_signing_key)
    # convert the HASHING result to a URL ENCODED base64 string.
    api_signature_encoded = (Base64.strict_encode64(api_signature))
    # AUTHORIZATION STRING - ESCAPED
    api_authorization_string = ('OAuth consumer_key="'+api_access_key_id+'",signature_method="'+api_signature_method+'",timestamp="'+CGI.escape(api_timestamp)+'",nonce="'+CGI.escape(api_nonce)+'",version="'+CGI.escape(api_version)+'",signature="'+CGI.escape(api_signature_encoded)+'"')
    # FARADAY OBJECT
    connect_token_request = Faraday.new(url: 'https://account.api.here.com') do |faraday|
        faraday.response :logger, nil, bodies: true
        faraday.request :json
        faraday.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
        faraday.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        faraday.headers['Authorization'] = api_authorization_string
        faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
    end
    # FARADAY POST         
    response_token_request= connect_token_request.post('/oauth2/token', 'grant_type=client_credentials' )
    # CHECK THE RESULT  
    puts response_token_request.body 
           
    @json = JSON.parse(response_token_request.body)
    req_status = @json['httpStatus']
    
    puts "The status returned in the body is:::: #{req_status}"
    puts "===== ///// ======"
    puts "===== ///// ======"
    req_error_code = @json['errorCode']
    
    puts "The ERROR CODE returned in the body is:::: #{req_error_code}"
    
end
```

Comment: yes, please check section "C) Create the signing key" of this document:  https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/sdk.html#step-2-create-a-signature

Comment: Double check your key, secret and escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know RoR but I had the same problem in Javascript and this script solved my problem:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const cryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
const btoa = require('btoa');

exports.getToken = (app_key, app_secret) => {
    let url = "https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token";
    let key = encodeURI(app_key);
    let secret = encodeURI(app_secret);
    let nonce = btoa(Math.random().toString(36)).substring(2, 13);
    let timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000);
    let normalizedUrl = encodeURIComponent(url);
    let signing_method = encodeURI("HMAC-SHA256");
    let sig_string = "oauth_consumer_key="
        .concat(key)
        .concat("&oauth_nonce=")
        .concat(nonce)
        .concat("&oauth_signature_method=")
        .concat(signing_method)
        .concat("&oauth_timestamp=")
        .concat(timestamp)
        .concat("&").concat("oauth_version=1.0");
    let normalised_string = "POST&".concat(normalizedUrl).concat("&").concat(encodeURIComponent(sig_string));
    let signingKey = secret.concat("&");
    let digest = cryptoJS.HmacSHA256(normalised_string, signingKey);
    let signature = cryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(digest);
    let auth = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="'
        .concat(key)
        .concat('",oauth_signature_method="')
        .concat(signing_method)
        .concat('",oauth_signature="')
        .concat(encodeURIComponent(signature))
        .concat('",oauth_timestamp="')
        .concat(timestamp)
        .concat('",oauth_nonce="')
        .concat(nonce)
        .concat('",oauth_version="1.0"')
    return axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify({grantType: "client_credentials"}),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Authorization': auth
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Erik Lima. I got this working on vanilla JS  as well (and on erb in  one of the app views as well) but this does not solve the problem. I need this to work from within one of the app controllers. I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I looked at the SHA256/Base64 strings all seem ok ... any other suggestion?